# How to secure local data in Android App

Tags: android, database, sqlite, security, apk

There is quite  alot of topics referencing that one, but none of them satisfys me.

I am faced with one problem. Let's say that I have simple android application which intention is to read/update/insert/delete data from **local database**.
Now my question is, how to make this database inaccessible if someone stole the phone and try to access it with usb cable?
What is the best way to secure data from that kind of access?
As far as i know, if I use for example SharedPreferences or Sqlite, those files are then stored and can be access via usb cable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my question is, how to make this database inaccessible if someone stole the phone and try to access it with usb cable?

Use an encrypted database, such as [SQLCipher for Android](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/), with a user-supplied passphrase.

Comment: "User-supplied" is important; otherwise, the thief can just start the app, or read the password from wherever the app has stored it.